# Is time of submission of a question or an answer associated with more or less views and votes?

Tags: discussion

I have submitted several posts to Academia and received very variable feedbacks in terms of views and votes.

It seems to me that choosing a specific time of submission (typically working hours in US time zones) leads to more views and votes.

Is this true?

Comment: If you're game for some statistical analysis, [the data is available](https://data.stackexchange.com/academia/query/new).